# Assign a static function to a variable in PHP

Tags: php, functional-programming

I would like to assign a static function to a variable so that I can send it around as a parameter. For example:

```
class Foo{
    private static function privateStaticFunction($arg1,$arg2){
      //compute stuff on the args          
    }

    public static function publicStaticFunction($foo,$bar){

         //works
         $var = function(){
                   //do stuff
                };

         //also works
         $var = function($someArg,$someArg2){
                   //do stuff
         };

         //Fatal error: Undefined class constant 'privateStaticFunction'                    
         $var = self::privateStaticMethod;

         //same error
         $var = Foo::privateStaticFunction;

         //compiles, but errors when I try to run $var() somewhere else, as expected
         //Fatal error: Call to private method Foo::privateStaticMethod() from context ''
         $var = function(){
             return Foo::privateStaticMethod(); 
         }; 
    }
}
```

I've tried a few more variations but none of them worked.

I don't even expect this sort of functional hacking to work with PHP but hey, who knows?

Is it possible to do that in PHP or will I need to come up with some hack using `eval`?

**P.S.:** LawnGnome on **##php** mentioned something about it being possible to do what I want using `array('Foo','privateStaticMethod')` but I didn't understand what he meant and I didn't press him further as he looked busy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to use [call_user_func](http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func.php) with an array argument.

```
$var = array('Foo','privateStaticMethod');
call_user_func($var);
```

Note that the "private" specifier on that method will make it only callable this way within the `Foo` class.

call_user_func takes a [callable](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.callable.php) as the first argument. Note that as of PHP 5.2.3, it is possible to avoid the array notation in your case.

> Static class methods can also be passed without instantiating an
>   object of that class by passing the class name instead of an object at
>   index 0. As of PHP 5.2.3, it is also possible to pass
>   'ClassName::methodName'.

Comment: perfect answer. however, when trying to `call_user_func` that from within yet another closure (all inside the class though) I can't seem to access the private method. **That's another matter though.** Not related to this. But closures in classes should be able to see that class' private methods, right?

Comment: AFAIK, a closure defined in a class does not get related to the class at all, so the rules of class access should be the same as an external function calling your private method. But you might solve your problem with [Closure::bindTo](http://php.net/manual/en/closure.bindto.php).

Answer (score 3):

As a note, you should set your static variable as so:

```
static $privateStaticMethod;

$var = self::$privateStaticMethod;
```

Leaving off a `$` when using `self::` will try to access a class CONSTANT and not a variable.

In actuality, I think you meant this line to be:

```
//Fatal error: Undefined class constant 'privateStaticFunction'                    
$var = self::privateStaticFunction("arga", "argb");
```

If you are on PHP 5.4 you can do the following within your `publicStaticFunction`:

```
$var = function(){
    return self::privateStaticFunction(); 
}; 

$var();
```

Within PHP 5.4, PHP allows you to access `class scope` from lambda functions.

Also, have you looked into `ReflectionClass`?

The following would be used to replace `call_user_func_array()` in a more OOP style:

```
<?php
$rc = new ReflectionClass('SomeClass');
$class = $rc->newInstanceArgs(array('foo', 'bar'));

echo $class->doSomething();
```

You could write your own class to use [`ReflectionMethod`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.reflectionmethod.php) which implements [`ReflectionClass`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.reflectionclass.php) and use `setAccessible()` to allow access to protected and private methods.

Comment: dead on on the doubt raised by my comment. I need 5.4 I think. Too bad I can't award two right answers.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I did to solve my issue

```
class test{
  static function Unix($arr){return implode("/",$arr);}
  static function Windows($arr){return implode("\\",$arr);}
  function test(){
    $slash = "Unix";
    echo self::$slash(["path","to","a","folder"]);
  }
}
```

Comment: I have a feeling this wont work on old versions of php